# How to save text typed in a edittext in a button click via coding, directly to the D' drive while device is connected with data cable in Android?

Tags: android

I am having two edittextbox and one button for synchronizing. The user will type their name and age in two editextbox. Whenever I press the synchronizing button, The data entered in the edittextboxes should be stored and updated everytime in the "D" drive in the PC as device is connected with PC using data cable.

Comment: android phone does not "own" the drives on your PC so you cannot write directly on to them.

Comment: @mwengler - should make that an answer since it IS the answer :)

Comment: @Yasir - you could still do this using sockets and doing it over a wifi network. It's just not possible using a data cable

Comment: Oh than q so much.. Mr.mwengler! Then how synchronizing process between phone and pc are done?

Comment: Than q for your answer Mr.dymmeh...!

Comment: Synchronizing between phone and PC via cable is done with code written for/on the PC, not the device.

Comment: If you have credentials on the PC then you could write a very complicated program which would get access to your PC file system and put files there.  But probably not over the USB cable, that I know of.  You do not gain "priveleges" on the PC's disks just by plugging a USB cable into the PC.